# Does $G$ have an Euler circuit??

Tags: graph-theory

The set of the vertices of the graph $G$ is $V=\{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. The vertices i and j are connected with an edge if and only if $|i-j| \mod 3 \in \{0,1 \}$.

Does $G$ have an Euler circuit??

I drawed the graph:

[image]

Comment: Well, what do you need to check? And with over 1000 rep, you should know by now to include your attempts or thoughts about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: a connected graph has an Eulerian circuit iff all of its vertices have even degree. What is the degree of vertex 1?

Comment: I added the graph at my post, and if I did it right, the vertices $1$ and $6$ have an odd degree, so it has not an Eulerian circuit. Is this correct??

Comment: Yes. (Whoops, in my original post, I meant vertex 1 instead of vertex 0, since vertex 1 has an odd degree).

Comment: And what's about an Eulerian path?

Comment: A connected graph has an Eulerian path iff either all the vertices have even degree (in which case the path is just a cycle) or if exactly two vertices have odd degree (in which case these two vertices must be the endpoints of the path). Since your graph has exactly two degrees of odd degree, it has an Eulerian path (namely, one from vertex 1 to vertex 6).

Comment: Since I had done accidentally an error at my graph, all the vertices have even degree, so it has an Eulerian circuit and also an Eulerian path, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error at your graph.The edge $1-6$ shouln't exist,because $|1-6| \mod 3=5 \mod 3=2 \notin \{ 0,1\}$.
Therefore,all the vertices have an even degree and so your graph $G$ has an Eulerian circuit.

Comment: Oh, you're right.. Thank you for noticing it!!!